# Set() is not working in Flutter when I use Flutter Hooks

Tags: flutter, set, flutter-hooks

I wanted to create a checklist for the programming languages I know. I have used Set() to contain the data. But when I use it in the CheckboxListTile() it is not checking the box in the UI. I wanted to do it with using flutter_hooks.

1. I have created an enum for ProgrammingLanguages.

`enum ProgrammingLanguages { C, DART, PYTHON, JAVASCRIPT }`

2. Then I have initialised the set in stateless Widget class like this

`final _selectedLanguages = useState<Set>(Set<ProgrammingLanguages>());`

3. In the build I have added a CheckBoxListTile like this.

```
CheckboxListTile(
  title: Text('C'),
  value: _selectedLanguages.value.contains(ProgrammingLanguages.C),
  onChanged: (value) {
     value
      ? _selectedLanguages.value.remove(ProgrammingLanguages.C)
      : _selectedLanguages.value.add(ProgrammingLanguages.C);
  }),
```

But in the final UI I am not able to activate the check box. Please help.

Comment: and where are you calling `Set.add`? `onChanged` takes a `bool` parameter and you have to use it when changing `_selectedLanguages.value` - btw instead of `Set<ProgrammingLanguages>` better use `Map<ProgrammingLanguages, bool>`

Comment: I didnt use map because I dont want to repeat values. Set contains unique items but map can contain duplicates right.

Comment: but as you can see the code is much more simple than in `Set` - you dont have to use any `add` / `remove` - you just do `map.value[ProgrammingLanguages.DART] = b;` thats all

Comment: and if you _really_ want to use `Set`s then try: `class Langs extends HookWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final langs = useState<Set<ProgrammingLanguages>>({});
print(langs.value);
return Column(
children: [
for (var l in ProgrammingLanguages.values)
Row(
children: [
Checkbox(
value: langs.value.contains(l),
onChanged: (b) => langs.value = b? langs.value.union({l}) : langs.value.difference({l}),
),
Text(l.toString()),
],
),
],
);
}
}`